# adding JS code only into Blog posts that are next to domain.com/blog/some-post/ and exclude in pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, google-analytics

I have my blog running on same domain at domain.com/blog/

so I want to add some advertising code on my blog posts, just on blog posts, and not show that code anywhere in the home or other pages in the same wordpress

is it possible at all with some plugins or some thing with out changing the core code?

please help me.

Comment: its much helpful to learn if you could explain the reason before just down-voting a question |)

Answer (score 0):

You can always add the code manually, but I think this is what you are looking for: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-plugin-for-simple-google-adsense-insertion/